# An overlay file system implementation for Linux that can present modified meta-data?

Tags: linux

I am looking for an overlay file system that can present a set of underlying files and folders but with modified owner and group. Is there such a thing?

The idea is to share the same set of data across several `userns`-based LXC guests.

So the mapping should be from one range of UIDs and GIDs to another (equally big) range of UIDs and GIDs (subordinate on the host).

Comment: Modified according to what rules? All to one user? A uid-to-uid map? A list of filename-uid pairs?

Comment: @Gilles: yes, UID to UID and GID to GID. This should be more or less obvious from the mentioning of `userns`, but let's make it explicit :)

Comment: Does the obvious candidate bindfs work for you? ([example](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount/198591#198591)) It does uid/gid mappings, but I'm not sure if that will help with your use case, since its mappins are inside whatever namespace the bindfs process runs, not between namespaces.

Comment: @Gilles: it might, still looking into it. Feel free to write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/) filesystem (based on [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)) is an overlay filesystem with the capability to remap user and group IDs. The mappings must be given on the `bindfs` command line when mounting the filesystem, with the `--map` command line option or `map` mount option. A mapping of the form `123/456` causes files owned by user 123 to be shown as owned by user 456. A mapping `@123/456` does the same for groups. You can use user and group names that are visible to the bindfs process. Beware that only traditional permissions are affected, ACL entries are not remapped.

Example:

```
bindfs --map=123/456:@staff/nogroup /srv/shared/daat /srv/containers/foo/data
```

I'm not sure if this would help you since it doesn't do remapping *between* user namespaces, the remapping is done in the namespace of the `bindfs` process.